# okhttp3: cookieJar: how to have saveFromResponse always called with all response cookies

Tags: okhttp

It looks like cookieJar.saveFromResponse(...) will not be called if Cookie.parseAll(...) returns an empty Cookie List: (https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http/HttpEngine.java#L867)

and Cookie.parseAll(...) excludes response cookies based on domain matching and other logic:(https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Cookie.java#L302)

Is it possible to bypass the Cookie.parse domain matching logic so that cookieJar.saveFromResponse(...) is called with response cookies that haven't been whittled down by domain?